# A word for "untranslatable" words from other languages

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Speakers of many languages treat as a cultural good that their language possesses words which are "untranslatable". Of course, that can be challenged or qualified, but this phenomenon is common enough that it deserves a word or phrase in English to describe it: a semantic equivalent of "shibboleth".

Does anyone know of such a word to collectively describe these assertions?

Examples of such claimed words include

- Sehnsucht
- Heimat
- Gwybodaeth

What these words share, beyond difficulty in translating, is that they are often claimed to be a cultural lodestone for the source language.

Comment: Agreed this is a duplciate. Sorry about that. Is there anything I ought to do? Delete, etc?

Answer (score 0):

I've studied a few foreign languages; and, every now and then, a teacher would remark to the effect that, 'There's no easy way to say this in English.'  Which was, probably, true until the word was used in context; and the meaning would suddenly become clear.

Plain and simple:  I call such words and phrases, 'linguistic enigmas'.  On my more facetious days I call them, 'newspeak'.